# X509 server authentication in TCP server

Tags: go, server, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I am using the following C# code:

```
netStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
var cert = new X509Certificate2("mycert.pfx", "123456");
netStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert);
```

What would be the equivalent of X509 server authentication (if the server is using TCP protocol) in Golang?

This is the Golang code I'm currently using:

```
func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":42127")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer l.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024 * 8)

    reqLen, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
    }

    conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
    conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried using the `tls` package? Note that the Go library is expecting PEM encoded certificates and keys.

Comment: try http://godoc.org/crypto/x509 ?

Comment: @holys it's even easier than that: http://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Certificate